# Unable to Connect My HTC Desire SV to My laptop: Unknown Device

Tags: htc-desire, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

When I'm connecting my HTC DESIRE SV I'm getting a message

> USB Device Not Recognized
>
> One of the USB devices attached to this computer has malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it.

I'm following all [the steps mentioned on HTC's main site](http://www.htc.com/in/support/howto.aspx?p_id=526&id=286846&p_name=htc-desire-sv). I have tried many times (Re-installed the HTC Sync, restarted my PC and Phone) but still same problem.

What can I do to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Install the HTC drivers for your phone. You can usually find them on your phone providers website, for example Galaxy S3 from Verizon can be found [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535MBBVZW)

Comment: Nothing is there :(

Comment: Which HTC do u have ?

Comment: Friends the problem was with DataCable, after changing the datacable it works fine :)